# True or false? (Ridge regression has higher error rate than standard linear regression for test set)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, error, ridge-regression

When using ridge regression, we would expect the error/loss function on the test set to be higher than if we used standard linear regression with no penalty.

I know that for the training set, the answer to the above question is true (because ridge regression is based on training set, and as such the error will be lower due to potential overfitting), but not sure in the case of the test set?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what "error rate" might mean in this context?  The answer could be either true or false depending on what meaning you intend.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to say that the error on the test set is going to be worse when using Ridge-Regression. If the linear regression was representing the true model underlying the data generation process, then yes, we would expect that the Ridge-Regression error, due to model mis-specification, must be higher.

But this hinges on the premise that the linear model is consistent with the underlying data generation process, which in general never holds. In fact, both models will be mis-specified in most cases.

The question here is more like, which model generalizes better to a test set. And the point about the Ridge-regression is that it is able to penalize the complexity of the model, whereas linear regression does not.

This implies that the linear regression under high model complexity can be subject to overfitting while Ridge-regression, to some extent, can be mitigate this. And, thus, we would expect that in a wide domain of problem sets with a lot of regressors, the Ridge regression may have a better Generalization behavior than the standard linear regression without parameter penalty.

*So the statement above certainly false for the test set. But with almost certainty, the linear regression will be more "accurate" on the training set than the Ridge Regression. This is because the linear regression has no restrictions and thus fill always "fit" better than a nested model that has more restrictions.*

Comment: Ah ok, so in other words, the statement is false?

Thank you very much for your help and your time

Comment: Yes it is certainly false regarding the test set. But in the training set, the linear regression will almost certainly beat the Ridge-Regression.